# Stack build fails due to mintty

Tags: haskell, servant

on loading a new project using `stack new project-name servant`
and running `stack build` the build fails  with the following message

```
mintty              > src\System\Console\MinTTY.hs:31:1: error:
mintty              >     Could not find module `System.Console.MinTTY.Win32'
mintty              >     Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
mintty              >    |
mintty              > 31 | import qualified System.Console.MinTTY.Win32 as Win32 (isMinTTY, isMinTTYHandle)
mintty              >    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
mintty              >
```

I found that mintty is a terminal emulator why is that a requirement for building my project.
I am running this on a windows 10 pc.

Update:

I referred to stack.yml in older project and used the older url for resolver and it started working

older:

```
resolver:
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/18/16.yaml
```

current: The one that was failing

```
resolver:
  url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commercialhaskell/stackage-snapshots/master/lts/18/17.yaml
```

Comment: um... I think it should work fine. have you tried `stack purge` first? to delete all stack work from previous builds. If that doesn't work, you can try yo pin [mintty](https://www.stackage.org/lts-18.16/package/mintty-0.1.2) version from `lts-18.16` in `extra-deps`

Comment: See also my workarounds on reddit: https://reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/qwsvg4/minttywin32/hl4yz39/